# User manual text file not available in the exe version

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've just made my program an exe via publish in visual studio. In that i included a usermanual.txt and a aboutus.txt file which are in bin>debug folder. After i published the program and run it. Those files are not viewing saying cannot find the file. How can i fix this

Comment: Move them to the release folder. `bin\debug* is (just as the name says) for the **debug** version. (Think about it: Why would they put a **debug** folder anywhere for any reason except for use in the **debug** version?)

Comment: this works but what if i need to do this in different computer. i could not do it in them

Comment: Then you properly package them when you publish your application, so they'll be in the proper location when your app is installed by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your files are included in Solution Explorer. If not, add them (`Right click on project -> Add -> Existing item...` then select them from disk).

This way your manuals will be part of your project.

Then, you should setup that those files are copied to same folder as your exe (`bin\debug` or `bin\release`). To to that right click on them, select `Properties` and notice `Copy to output directory` setting. It has to have "Always" or "Copy if newer" option selected.

In your code, to open file, use path like this:

```
string userManualPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "usermanual.txt");
```

that will open file in same directory as application's .exe.

When editing your manual (adding some new text), edit the one in solution, and the changes will reflect to either debug or release or published version.

Comment: ok that sounds good, btw, when i setting the file to open here "userManual.txt" how set the path as release/userManual.txt ? once i removed this still it shows that debug/userManual is missing

richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(@"userManual.txt");

Comment: @FaadilFarick I'm not sure I understood you correctly, but you can open file relative to your exe. I have edited my answer, check it out.

Comment: damn, thank you man i think i haven;t add that to release folder and now it works. thank you...